# Mapped Array to Observable, updating Array propagate to Observable?

Tags: typescript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am creating Observable from Array.

When I use simple "map" without the   + " is a number" addition, all works

How to make the Observable transform data with this addition.

This is crucial part for me to use rxjs for tracking the state and enfoce immutability, I will only change the state and rxjs complex functions will parse the data realtime.

I know there are some solutions, but I need this simple example to work somehow.

Anyone?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Rx from 'rxjs/Rx'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="addToArray()">Add</button>
    <ul>
      <li *ngFor="let item of data$ | async">{{ item }}</li>
    </ul>


  `
})
export class AppComponent {

  data = ["one","two","three"]
  data$: Observable<Array<string>>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.data$ = Rx.Observable.from(this.data)
      .map(data => {
        return data + " is a number"
      })
  }

  addToArray() {
    this.data.push('more numbers')
  }
}
```

The .from manual: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/from.md

Comment: What exactly is failing? map functions perfectly fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/91woww5a/1/ Are you talking about the typescript?

Comment: This works, no problem. But when you assign it to this.data$ and then subscribe with | async pipe, it does not work. Try to copy paste, it will not work. The important part is when I add new element, to have everything propagate well.

Comment: "updating array propagate to Observable" I'm not quite sure what all is broken here, but, you can't create an Observable from an array, then push more values to the array to update the Observable. It's sounding like you may need a subject... Read through this https://coryrylan.com/blog/angular-2-observable-data-services it seems to cover what you're after.

Comment: I added new plunkr : http://plnkr.co/edit/z26799bSy17mAL4P5MiD?p=preview . In this example, I just need somehow to put "x" as observable, to perform transformations on "x" before returning. Now with just return x all works, but I miss that transformation part for it to be complete

Comment: If you want to have transformations on each NEW item, I can write that up. Transforming your original array is a bit odd, as you could just do it manually beforehand since it's hardcoded.

Comment: Yes, please write that up also. Thank you very much.